# Clone my setup for multiple raspis

Tags: software-installation, setup

I'm going to have a bunch of people learning computing with raspis. I have my own 3b+ running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 set up with everything software- and config-wise I want the students to have. Is there a way to clone my raspi while giving the individuals their own accounts? But then if I did just a straight clone/duplication, could I go in and remove my account and let them set up their own -- with sudo privileges? Problematic is I want all the configs attached to my account (in my home directory) to be cloned, but given to each individual.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to define default setups for an account is done with `/etc/skel`. If a new account is created that skeleton is used to create the users home directory. Normally you only find the configuration files for bash in it. Check with `ls -a /etc/skel/`.

I have never used a complete user account as skeleton but it is worth a try for your needs. So when a user logs in the first time and its account is created its home directory is copied from `/etc/skel` but with individual user rights.

If you like to get further information you can ask google with [How to use skel](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=i3u5XPWGCcfMwQL7yLvAAg&q=How+to+use+skel&btnK=Google+Search&oq=How+to+use+skel). You will find millions of matches. The second one is [Linux Howtos: Tips and Tricks -> Using /etc/skel](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/using_skel.htm)

Comment: Any good documentation, tutorial for that you might suggest?

Comment: @147pm I have updated the answer with the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly MATE 18.04 for the Pi is still in beta and has some outstanding issues.

Ubuntu uses Network Manager for networking, and normally Predictable Network Names, which are not transferable from machine to machine.

If you overcome these issues the image should be transferable - depending on exactly what you want to setup this can be handled by skel.

Another approach I use is to setup a  basic Administrative user and write a script to initialise user settings.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. You would point me back to Rasbian?